# How to use same component twice with different paths in app routing module

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-routing, angular-router

I have created 2 different methods and want to call on one component by passing id and state.
I need to create 2 paths in routing module with same components.

Like this:

```
{path:'Generatereport/:state/:city/:status/:financedBy',component:GeneratereportComponent},
{path:'Generatereport/:state',component:GeneratereportComponent},
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use queryParams when 2 paths in the routing module with the same components

Remove the below routing

```
{path:'Generatereport/:state/:city/:status/:financedBy',component:GeneratereportComponent},
```

Replace with the below routing

```
{path:'Generatereport',component:GeneratereportComponent},
```

Add the below code to the button action

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {}

 this.router.navigate(['/Generatereport/'], {
    queryParams: {
                    state: 'State',
                    city: 'City',
                    status:'OK',
                    financedBy:'Financed By'
                  }
  });
```

Retrieve data from the GeneratereportComponent

```
 constructor(private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this._Activatedroute.queryParams.subscribe((v) => {
      console.log(v);
    });
  }
```